# Does a high run queue length average result in poor performance for a web server?

Tags: sar

I'm trying to narrow down the list of suspects of web servers that perform moderately well most of the time with occasional bouts of poor performance.  I'm analyzing the data collected and summarized by sar.  I've noticed a few things, one of which is high number of tasks in the run queue.

```
10:15:01 AM   runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15   blocked
10:25:01 AM         2       150      0.05      0.05      0.06         0
10:35:01 AM         4       149      0.08      0.12      0.09         0
10:45:01 AM         6       150      0.13      0.19      0.15         0
10:55:01 AM         1       150      0.08      0.10      0.13         0
11:05:01 AM         4       150      0.20      0.35      0.23         0
11:15:01 AM         3       149      0.02      0.09      0.15         0
11:25:01 AM         7       149      0.04      0.05      0.11         0
11:35:01 AM         4       150      0.14      0.15      0.13         0
11:45:01 AM         6       150      0.27      0.18      0.16         0
11:55:01 AM         5       150      0.08      0.10      0.13         0
12:05:01 PM         3       149      0.35      0.40      0.26         0
12:15:01 PM        19       155      0.02      0.10      0.16         1
12:25:01 PM         2       150      0.00      0.07      0.12         0
12:35:02 PM         3       151      0.58      0.24      0.17         0
12:45:01 PM         8       150      0.02      0.13      0.15         0
12:55:01 PM         6       149      0.81      0.29      0.18         0
01:05:01 PM         3       148      0.00      0.09      0.13         0
01:15:01 PM         7       149      0.00      0.04      0.11         0
```

I believe these are 10 minute averages.

Is this an indicator that the web server is not performing as fast as it could if the average run queue length was lower?

Comment: The runq-sz and plist-sz fields are snapshots in time. They are not 10min averages. It's possible to have 19 items in your runqueue and have a loadavg(1) < 1.00, because a fork-heavy process could exit quickly at the moment that you poll with sa. I would shift the sa collector with a sub-60 second sleep step to see if you're just getting ballooned stats from other quick cron jobs that run at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Your load average remains low throughout this. I think it would be difficult to determine much with such large delays between readings. A high run queue with a corresponding high load would indicate a resource issue. I don't think that's the case here. How are you quantifying "poor performance"?

Comment: I was quantifying poor performance as slower page-load times.

Comment: You need more granular monitoring. What does `top` show at the slow performance periods?

Comment: It shows cpu core 0 near 100% utilization (or rather near 0% idle).  Memory looks fine.  No single process is dominating, but I'm going to try to change the cpu affinity with some processes.

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely a symptom of poor performance (eg. long processing time per processing item for some items combined with load balancing that is agnostic about the work involved in each query imbalancing the load toward one server) than its cause.